# Accordionpane count number of divisions inside and store in an array

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages, accordionpane

```
 <asp:accordionpane id="colors">

   <header> colors</header>

   <content>
    <div> blue </div>
    <div> red  </div>
    <div> gray </div>
   </content>

 </accordionpane>
```

is there a way to find no of divs and traverse the loop
and store there names in arrays say string `colors{} = accordionpane.div("blue"), accordionpane.div("red"), accordionpane.div("gray")`

or is there a way to find an accordionpane has div or not

Comment: On client- or on serverside? I ask because if you want to access your divs on serverside, you should consider to use `Panel`s instead (which are also rendered as `div`s).

Comment: sorry , to be precise with my question i will know how many accordionpane exist from accordion.panes.count , likewise is there a way to know how many divs an accordion pane has...

Comment: thus traversing all the divs from all the accordion panes of the main Accordion control...

Comment: As i've already commented, make it `runat=server` (or even better- a `Panel`) if you want to access it on serverside. Otherwise you cannot traverse the `colors.Controls` since it's empty.

Comment: k, yeah i thought the same but as i have too many pages based on divs i was thinking of some solution to retaining divs....thanks for ur reply

Answer (score 1):

Make it `runat=server` (or even better- a [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx)) if you want to access it on serverside. Otherwise you cannot traverse the `colors.Controls` since it's empty.

```
<asp:accordionpane id="colors">

   <header> colors</header>

   <content>
    <asp:Panel id="pnlBlue" runat="server"> blue </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel id="pnlRed" runat="server"> red  </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel id="pnlGray" runat="server"> gray </asp:Panel>
   </content>

</accordionpane>
```

Now this Linq query works:

```
Dim panelText = From p In colors.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)()
    Select p.Controls.OfType(Of LiteralControl)().First().Text.Trim()
Dim count As Int32 = panelText.Count()
Dim allColors = String.Join(",", panelText)
```